# Position Actor Bottom Right Of Viewport

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I am using scene2d, and I want to position a custom actor I created, that just extends Image and allows me to play animations. I am having problems keeping the actor in the bottom right of the screen. When I shrink window out of 16:9 ratio, the actor goes up the side (Up on y axis) instead of staying in bottom. The actor is an AnimActor (I created), which will work the same as an Image. I am trying to make a loading symbol. I do resize the view port correctly. Here's the code :

```
    stage = new Stage(viewport);
    Animation anim = Main.loadingSymbol;
    anim.setFrameSize(new Vector2(camera.viewportWidth / 10, camera.viewportWidth / 10));
    loadingSymbolActor = new AnimActor(anim);
    table = new Table(new Skin());
    table.setBounds(0, 0, stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());
    table.add(loadingSymbolActor);
    table.pack();
    table.align(Align.bottomRight);
    stage.addActor(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Table`s are mainly for static UI layout, since it is not easy to add/remove or move actors once they are laid out. There probably isn't much I can tell you that the libGDX wiki doesn't, it has a very good explanation on `Table`s [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table).

But if the issue is to do with resizing, make sure you update your `Stage` camera correctly in the resize method. Maybe also change your `Table` bounds in the resize method, and set `table.setFillParent(true)` after initialising your `Table`.

To fix your `Actor` to the bottom right of the `Table`, you can try `table.add(loadingSymbolActor).bottom().right();`.